# How to recognise a song by listening using Echonest for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-fingerprinting

I want to implement a functionality similar to the one integrated in Shazam app. I want my app by pressing to a button to "listen" for a song and after some time to "guess" the song or give some predictions using Echonest api for iOS. I was searching the web and so far I've learned the I need to send the fingerprint to the Echonest server and give me response with the song info. But somewhere I've read that that functionality will be no more available. Also tried to upload the whole mp3 file to their server and the response is always an empty one. Does anyone has experience with this issue and tell me where I'm wrong?
I've used [echoprint](https://github.com/rexstjohn/echoprint-ios-sample) but no success.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Well, as far as I can see, there was an answer to this question but it is removed (don't know why). As far as I can remember there was some other(maybe native) libraries but I'm not sure... Anyway I still don't have a solution.

Comment: I am also searching for the same :(